# login validation in flex

Tags: apache-flex, authentication

i am new to flex, i have a problem while username and password validation.i retrieved data (username and password)from an xml doc using http service but the problem is that i have to verify the username and password entered by he user with the username and password of the xml doc...can anyone tell me how is it possible?

my xml doc is as follows:

```
<employees>
  <employee>
    <username>ndo1</username>
    <password>1234</password>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <username>ndo2</username>
    <password>1234</password>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <username>ndo3</username>
    <password>1234</password>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <username>ndo4</username>
    <password>1234</password>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <username>ndo5</username>
    <password>1234</password>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a big security leak if you are trying to transfer the account informations to the client. You should send the login credentials to the server, which verifies if the login is valid.

So you have to implement a remote API which provides this functionality. Search the web and/or StackOverflow for examples how to implement authentication with Flex.

A good starting point is the Flex documentation themself: [Applying Flex Security](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=security2_01.html)

Comment: +1.  To be clearer: Using FireBug (or similar), the user would be able to read the XML you send to the client, and read out the full list of usernames and passwords, even if you're using HTTPS to transfer the data to the client.  Don't send authentication credentials over the wire.

Comment: @Andrew Aylett: Thanks for the collaboration! ;-)